# Why triggerAtTime in AlarmManager.setRepeating doesn't work

Tags: android

```
AlarmManager mgr=
      (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, AlarmReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0);
mgr.setRepeating(
  AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
  System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000,
  1000, pi);
```

According to android doc

> triggerAtMillis   time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

the action should start right after 1 second, but it never gets called, why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` in the setRepeating() method, use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` like below,

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000, pi);
```

Comment: Thanks, checked the AlarmManager doc again. it depends on the type, with RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(); ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP needs coresponding SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()

Comment: The reason behind this is that ELAPSED_REALTIME is for setting alarms "after a certain amount of time has passed" and RTC is for alarms "at a certain wall clock time".

Answer (score 6):

I google quite a bit but seems no one run into the same issue.
finally i find I should use SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() instead.

For triggerAtMillis, since type is AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() 
should be used instead of 
    System.currentTimeMillis()

the issue is resolved.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj the issue this resolved with SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()